# How to deploy a compute instance with no public IP

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine, google-deployment-manager

How can I deploy a computer instance with no public IP using GCP Deployment Manager?

Looking at the yaml configuration file, I get an error if I don't include anything in `accessConfigs`. `networkInterfaces` is also mandatory. At the moment my configuration file for the resource looks like this:

```
- type: compute.v1.instance                                                                      
  name: cassandra-node-1                                                                           
  properties:                                                                                        
    zone: europe-west2-c                                                                             
    machineType: https://www.googleapis.com/compute/v1/projects/affable-seat-213016/zones/europe-west2-c/machineTypes/n1-standard-1                                                                   
    disks:                                                                                           
    - deviceName: boot                                                                                 
      boot: true                                                                                       
      autoDelete: true                                                                                 
      initializeParams:                                                                                  
        sourceImage: https://www.googleapis.com/compute/v1/projects/ubuntu-os-cloud/global/images/ubuntu-1604-xenial-v20181204                                                                        
      networkInterfaces:                                                                               
      - accessConfigs:
```

I have tried several combinations of `accessConfigs` and `networkInterfaces`, but so far only the ones that work are the ones with the snippet below, but that assigns a public IP to the instance.

```
networkInterfaces:                                                                               
- accessConfigs:                                                                                  
   - name: External NAT                                                                               
     type: ONE_TO_ONE_NAT
```

**EDIT**
Deploying with no `accessConfig` gives error:

> ERROR: (gcloud.deployment-manager.deployments.create) Error in
>   Operation [operation-1545956660669-57e0a1598ea49-702a8e20-89ae5f53]:
>   errors:                                                          -
>   code: CONDITION_NOT_MET
>   location: /deployments/test/resources/cassandra-node-1->$.properties
>   message: '"/networkInterfaces": domain: validation; keyword: type;
>   message: instance
>   does not match any allowed primitive type; allowed: ["array"]; found:
>   "null"'

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you remove the accessConfigs member completely, as opposed to providing an empty accessConfigs, the instance is created without an external IP address.

Comment: Doesn't work. `networkInterfaces` doesn't accept a null value. If you try to deploy without the element it gives this error: 
`message: '"/networkInterfaces": domain: validation; keyword: type; message: instance                                                                                                                   does not match any allowed primitive type; allowed: ["array"]; found: "null"'`

Comment: Yes, you still need to provide at least a network.  It's the accessConfigs portion that you should remove completely.

Comment: Example:

```resources:
- name: the-first-vm
  type: compute.v1.instance
  properties:
    zone: us-central1-f
    machineType: https://www.googleapis.com/compute/v1/projects/myproject/zones/us-central1-f/machineTypes/f1-micro
    disks:
    - deviceName: boot
      type: PERSISTENT
      boot: true
      autoDelete: true
      initializeParams:
        sourceImage: https://www.googleapis.com/compute/v1/projects/debian-cloud/global/images/family/debian-9
    networkInterfaces:
    - network: https://www.googleapis.com/compute/v1/projects/myproject/global/networks/default```

Comment: I didn't include the network, because as per the docs, it would use the default network. It seems a bit silly that we need to include a default value, just so DM accepts the yaml file. Thanks!

Comment: Ah, I see.  I have opened a bug internally and will follow up here when I have an update.  Thanks.